# Webpack -> sass-loader -> node-sass - SASS import: resolve nested depth 2 npm package import

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, sass, node-modules

I have the following structure for a web component:

```
-moduleA
   -node_modules
       -my-sass-package-a
           -node_modules
               -my-sass-package-b
                   _my-partial.scss
                   package.json
           _my-partial.scss
           package.json
   styles.scss
   package.json
```

In styles.scss I import a SCSS asset from `my-sass-package-a`:

```
@import 'my-sass-package-a/my-partial';
```

In `my-sass-package-a/my-partial` I import my-sass-package-b:

```
@import 'my-sass-package-b/my-partial';
```

sass-loader throws the following error (bur the error is really coming from the blackbox that is `node-sass`)

> SassError: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   my-sass-package-b/my-partial

The following SOs do not help and are not specifically addressing my context/case:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35018624/1258525 (this one does not work because they are hard coding the nested depth package, I cannot hard code "my-sass-package-b" into my `includePaths`
- [Importing Sass through npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283652/importing-sass-through-npm) (this one is not working with SASS npm packages but relative SASS assets)

This is issue is one of depth resolution in a nested dependencies.

- Is there a way to hook into node-sass resolution and provide hints to look in nested node_module at each resolution root context?

  - Is there a way to change node-sass options to recursively look for SASS packages in nested `node_modules` without harding coding `my-sass-package-b` into my `includePaths`, again this is not an option for me. (I do not see a [node-sass option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#usage-1) that help my scenario)